# Projecting a quartered circle with a 50km radius in r/sf?

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, r-sf

I'm hoping to create a series of quartered circles (i.e. circles split into 4 equal quadrants), each with a 50km radius, that I can map onto various longitudes and latitudes throughout the United States. I'd also like the option to rotate these quartered circles as desired.

Using the code below (and guidance from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328707/how-do-i-partition-a-circle-into-equal-multipolygon-slices-with-sf-and-r)), I've been able to make the following start:

[New York State Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3khDF.png)

I have two questions:

1. How can I meaningfully set the radius of these circles? Is there a way to draw shapes a certain distance (in km) from a coordinate in a projected CRS? So far I'm defining the radius in terms of degrees of longitude and latitude, but distance would be more useful.
2. My circles appear to be turning into ellipses after projecting them and mapping them in WGS84. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

I would be happy to consider alternative approaches. Thanks!

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

#Two functions to create coordinate quartered circle polygons

#x = long, y = lay, r = radius, theta_rotate = rotation
st_wedge <- function(x,y,r,start,width, theta_rotate){
   n <- 20
      theta = seq(start+theta_rotate, start+width+theta_rotate, length=n)
      xarc = x + r*sin(theta) 
      yarc = y + r*cos(theta)
      xc = c(x, xarc, x) 
      yc = c(y, yarc, y)
      st_polygon(list(cbind(xc,yc)))   
}


st_wedges <- function(x, y, r, nsegs, theta_rotatex){
   width = (2*pi)/nsegs
   starts = (1:nsegs)*width
   polys = lapply(starts, function(s){st_wedge(x,y,r,s,width, theta_rotatex)})
   #Cast to crs 4326, WGS84
   mpoly = st_cast((st_sfc(polys, crs = 4326)), "MULTIPOLYGON")
   mpoly
}

#Create quartered sf circle polygon 
custom_circle_sf <- st_wedges(x = -76, y = 43, r = .3, nsegs = 4, theta_rotatex = 200) %>%
 st_sf() %>% 
   mutate(group = row_number()) %>% dplyr::select(group, geometry)

#Create New York State sf polygon
ny_map_sf <- map_data("state", region="new york")  %>% 
st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)   %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% 
   st_cast("POLYGON")

#Plot results
ggplot() +
   geom_sf(data=ny_map_sf,
           size = 1,
           colour = "blue", 
           fill   = "white") + 
   geom_sf(data=custom_circle_sf,
           size = .1,
           aes(fill=group),
           colour = "white")
```

Comment: I haven't run your code yet, but it looks like you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. You can cast your geometry to a US-based CRS with meters as its unit—[EPSG:4269](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4269/) is one. Then just use `sf::st_buffer` to make a circle of the right size. Probably an easier way to break that into wedges also with some `sf` functions, maybe by taking intersections between the buffer area and portions of the bounding box. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: Also it would be better to split the second question out into its own post

Comment: Thanks Camille. I was consider a solution along those lines (you are understanding correctly). 

I believe the idea for your described approach would be to 1) create a 2x2 “checkerboard” centered at the circle's center; 2) Give each checkerbox a length equal to the circle's radius; and 3) find a way to rotate this checkerboard a given number of degrees around the origin (i.e. the center of the circle).

Comment: I think I could use st_bbox to create the bounding box and then use st_split to divide the box into four quadrants. Does anything else sound preferable?

Comment: Yeah other than using `st_buffer` to get the circle, that's about what I'm imagining. Not sure I could work out a full answer but I'll keep thinking about this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is curious about splitting polygons in *sf* using R, this was how I went about solving this:

```
#Function to create circle with quadrants. Save desired projection as projected_crs
create_circle <- function(lat_x, long_y, theta_x, buffer_m){
   #Create circle with radius buffer_m centered at (lat_x, long_y)
   circle_buffer  <- st_point(c(lat_x, long_y)) %>%  st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
      st_cast("POINT")  %>% 
      st_transform(projected_crs) %>%
      st_buffer(buffer_m)
   
   #Create two orthogonal lines at origin 
   p1 <- rbind(c(lat_x,long_y - 1), c(lat_x,long_y + 1))
   p2 <- rbind(c(lat_x+1,long_y), c(lat_x-1,long_y))
   mls <- st_multilinestring(list(p1,p2))  %>% st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
      st_transform(projected_crs) 
   
   #Use orthogonal lines to split circle into 4 quadrants
   x1 <- st_split(circle_buffer, mls) 
   
   #Convert origin into projected CRS
   center_in_crs  <- st_point(c(lat_x, long_y)) %>% 
      st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>%
      st_transform(projected_crs)
   
   sp_obj <- x1 %>% st_collection_extract(type="POLYGON") %>%
      #Convert to spatial to use sp functions
      as_Spatial() %>% 
      #rotate x degrees
      elide(rotate = theta_x + 45, center  = center_in_crs[[1]]) %>% 
      #return to sf 
      st_as_sf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question 2: "circles appear to be turning into ellipses". If you add to your ggplot the coord_equal() function then the grid will be square, and the ellipses will be shown as circles.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful